# finding a general solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find a general solution for $x(x+y)y'=y(x-y)$ using the substitution method. I literally have no idea where to start with this. almost 2 hours into it and no meaningful progress. I really need some help

Comment: What do you mean by substitution method? Do you mean let $$y = v x \implies y' = v + v' x$$ If so, substitute both of those and solve the result Separable Equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the ODE explicit
$$
y'=\frac{y(x-y)}{x(x+y)}
$$
and recognize a homogeneous equation. Set $y=xu$ to get
$$
xu'+u=\frac{u(1-u)}{1+u}\iff xu'=-\frac{2u^2}{1+u}
$$
which can be separated and integrated.